# Understanding quantifiers in z3

Tags: python, lambda, z3, quantifiers

I'm trying to understand this example:

`solve([y == x + 1, ForAll([y], Implies(y <= 0, x < y))])`

but after reading the [explanation](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-quantifiers-and-lambda-binding) I still don't understand it.

How do you read this?
what is the meaning of []?

My wrong interpretation of this is.
"Given the theorem y == x + 1. Does it hold for all y such that Implies(y <= 0, x < y)?"
With this interpretation if I use `y = 0` and `x = -1` every constraint (Implies(y <= 0, x < y) is true since y <= 0 and x < y) is respected, but If I run this I find out that it's not solvable.

Do you have any hits to how to understand this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there're a couple of confusions here. Let's first sort out binding: In a quantifier context, the variable is independent, i.e., it can be renamed with no change to the semantics. So, your original:

```py
from z3 import *
x, y = Ints('x y')
solve([y == x + 1, ForAll([y], Implies(y <= 0, x < y))])
```

**is** exactly equivalent to:

```py
from z3 import *
x, y, z = Ints('x y z')
solve([y == x + 1, ForAll([z], Implies(z <= 0, x < z))])
```

Note that we replaced the `y` in the "scope" of `ForAll` to `z`, but left the one in the first conjunct untouched. You can only rename within the scope of `ForAll` (or `Exist`), not outside of it.

And both of these equivalent expressions are unsatisfiable. Why? The first conjunct is easy to satisfy; just pick an arbitrary `x`, and set `y` to be `x+1` and you're done. It's the second conjunct that's unsatisfiable. Because, no matter which `x` you choose to satisfy the first, you can always find a `z` that's less than that `x` (just pick `min(0, x-1)`), and the quantified formula becomes False for that assignment. And hence there are no solutions.

Now, let's consider the variant you had in your comments, with `x > z`:

```py
from z3 import *
x, y, z = Ints('x y z')
solve([y == x + 1, ForAll([z], Implies(z <= 0, x > z))])
```

Again, the first conjunct is easy to satisfy. And this time, so is the second, because you can pick a positive `x`, and that will be greater than all `z`'s so long as `z <= 0`, and thus the implication is always true. And that's exactly what z3 is telling you, when it gives you the satisfying assignment:

```py
[x = 2, y = 3]
```

Note that there's *nothing* in this assignment regarding the variable `z`. You cannot really give a model for a universally quantified formula; by definition it is **true** for all values of `z`.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Just some details. If I pick `x = -10` in the first equation ( the one with ` x<z`) then with `z = -5` that statement should be true right? So there are some value that satisfy the equation

Comment: No. Since the second clause is universally quantified, you need to be able to pick an `x` that makes it true for all integers `z`. And the whole thing is unsatisfiable precisely because you cannot find such an `x`.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it: You can think of the `ForAll` as an infinite conjunction; one for each integer value `z`. (i.e., `..., -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...`. Imagine what the formula would look like if you *expanded* it in this way and conjuncted all the terms. Now, to `solve`, you need to satisfy every single one of these infinite number of clauses. Now you can see the `x < z` variant is `unsat`, since there's no such `x` that's less than all negative integers, but `x > z` is `sat`, since any positive `x` will do, as any positive `x` will be greater than all `z <= 0`.

Comment: I think (hope) that I got it xD. Thank you, now I'm able to understand that example

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is a Python list; the outer one is a list of constraints (representing a conjunction) and the one in the `ForAll` is a list of constants to bind.

Note that the same constant name can be re-used. In this case, `y` in `y == x + 1` is a global existential and the `y` in the `ForAll` is a universally bound variable which also has the name `y`.

Comment: I think that written like this is too complicate for me to understand. So you are saying that the y in the ForAll is not the same of the y in y == x+1? If this is the case then the statment should be true right? The Forall part for how I interpret it seems always true.

Comment: The first `y` and the second `y` are independent. In a sense, you can read it as `[y == x + 1, ForAll([z], Implies(z <= 0, x < z))]`; and thus it is false, Because you can always find an `x` that's smaller than `z`.

Comment: @alias thank you for the answer. I find all of this more confusing, because if I write `[y == x + 1, ForAll([z], Implies(z <= 0, x > z))]` then why this should be true? I can always find and x that's grater then z. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Well, that’s the point it’s *not* true. Nothing in the above comments suggested that was true at all.

Comment: @alias but if I run it on python with y instead of z then that is true. https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-quantifiers-and-lambda-binding that's the example that I'm looking at

Comment: I just ran it myself. I get "no solution" with both `y` and `z`. So, I'm not sure how you're getting that output. Add the exact interaction you're having to your question.

Comment: @alias just run this `solve([y == x + 1, ForAll([y], Implies(y <= 0, x > y))])` you will get `x=2` and `y=3`. (with `x = Int('x')` and `y = Int('y')`

Comment: Your original question had `x < y`. In your comment you have `x > y`. Obviously, these are different queries.

Comment: @alias I know, that's because I can't understand why one is always false and the other has a solution.

Comment: I'll write an answer to explain; these comment boxes aren't suitable for long discussions like this.